# Merging 2 sql statements with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I've 2 tables, first one is users(13068), the other one invitations(211343)
fbuid on users is same with inviter on invitations.

So I'm trying export this 2 tables as an excel which should looks like this;

u.name, u.adress, u.fbuid ...., COUNT(i.id)

So for I've tried;

```
SELECT u.*,(SELECT COUNT(i.id) FROM invitations i WHERE i.isaccepted = 1 and i.inviter = u.fbuid) as chance FROM users WHERE u.datecreated BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01' LIMIT 0,50
```

and

```
SELECT *,COUNT(i.id) as chance FROM users u LEFT JOIN invitations i ON u.fbuid = i.inviter WHERE u.datecreated BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' and i.isaccepted=1 GROUP BY fbuid
```

Problem is left join gives only users with invitations, but only about 2000 users invited, I need to list all of them.

First one is with limit 50 tooks 36 seconds. I can't imagine how much took all records. Other than join what else I can do? Or how should be the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query with the `left join`:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(i.id) as chance
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     invitations i
     ON u.fbuid = i.inviter
WHERE u.datecreated BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' and i.isaccepted=1
GROUP BY fbuid;
```

The problem is that you are filtering on the `i` table in the `where` clause.  Because of the `left join`, this could have a value of `NULL`.  Move that condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(i.id) as chance
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     invitations i
     ON u.fbuid = i.inviter and i.isaccepted = 1
WHERE u.datecreated BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'
GROUP BY fbuid;
```

Comment: I really don't know is it working or not because query still didn't returned any result and I've added limit 50. I'm really desperate.

Comment: aand 5 record took 153 seconds, why I can't get it?

Comment: The first query is running a separate subquery on each row being output.  It will run faster with an index on `invitations(inviter, isaccepted, id)`.

Comment: Just I did that and you are right, I've selected fbuid column as index and then voila!

Comment: Thank you both, @Gordon Linoff,  you are a real life saver.